# Merge two columns and group them

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

For example I have this:

**name**

```
ID   | NAME
1    | Aiden
2    | Jackson
3    | Ethan
```

**name_old**

```
ID   | NAME
1    | Aiden
2    | Liam
3    | Mason
4    | Noah
5    | Ethan
```

And I want to get:

**results**

```
NAME
Aiden
Jackson
Ethan
Liam
Mason
Noah
```

I can not figure it out what query would do the job. I guess merge somehow than group by the result?

Comment: Isn't it just an `UNION` with `DISTINCT`?

Comment: The `UNION` is `DISTINCT` by default, the `UNION ALL` isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UNION` will take results from both part and merge common results.

```
select NAME from name
UNION
select NAME from name_old;
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fa80/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
declare @name table(id int identity(1,1),name varchar(50))
insert into @name select 'aiden'
insert into @name select 'jackson'
insert into @name select 'ethan'
insert into @name select 'stephen'

declare @name_old table(id int identity(1,1),name varchar(50))
insert into @name_old select 'aiden'
insert into @name_old select 'jackson'
insert into @name_old select 'ethan'
insert into @name_old select 'mason'
insert into @name_old select 'noah'
insert into @name_old select 'ethan'

select distinct t.name from
(
select name from @name
union
select name from @name_old
) as t
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use right outer join**

The RIGHT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the right table (table2), with the matching rows in the left table (table1). The result is NULL in the left side when there is no match.

```
SELECT NAME
 FROM name
 RIGHT JOIN name_old
 ON name.NAME=name_old.NAME;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_right.asp

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
SELECT NAME FROM NAME
UNION
SELECT NAME FROM NAME_OLD
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df3f0/1)